# Form dictionary like structure from the given tabs and data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the dictionary from tabs and data by iterating

I'm unable to form dictionary like structure and expected Output is mentioned

```js
const tabs = {
  first: 'first',
  second: 'second',
  third: 'third'
}

const data = {
  accounts: {
    members: [
      {
        node: {id: '1', name: 'first'}
      },
      {
        node: {id: '2', name: 'second'}
      },
      {
        node: {id: '3', name: 'third'}
      },
    ]
  }
}

let expectedOutput = {'first': '1','second':'2','third':'3'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an object **tabs**.  We can get key from this object using **Object.keys(object_name)**. It will simply return us an array of key.

`Object.keys(tabs)` **=> [first, second,third]**

**data.accounts.members** is also an array.We need to use array filter method to extract the node object from data.accounts.members array. Each item in array is an object. We can use object dot notation property to get value.

```
const filterarray = data.accounts.members.filter(it => it.node.name === tabs[item])[0]
```

To read first value from array just simply use filterarray[0] index.

Reduce need initial value which is an empty object.We are appending data in this object.

We can simply add data in object using **object[key] = value**
Here key will be tabs key. tabs is also an object we need to read the value of that key and store result in object result[tabs[item]] = filterarray.node.id

Once reduce is over we will get result.

```js
const tabs = {
  first: 'first',
  second: 'second',
  third: 'third'
}

const data = {
  accounts: {
    members: [{
        node: {
          id: '1',
          name: 'first'
        }
      },
      {
        node: {
          id: '2',
          name: 'second'
        }
      },
      {
        node: {
          id: '3',
          name: 'third'
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}

const expectedOut =
  Object.keys(tabs).reduce(
    (result, item) => {
      const ch = data.accounts.members.filter(it => it.node.name === tabs[item])[0]
      result[tabs[item]] = ch.node.id
      return result
    }, {})
console.log(expectedOut)
```

Comment: just use JSON.stringfy(object). it will give you json structure.